Awk to pick up json values
I am trying to get the job status from the below json file.. but while using awk it is returning

{
    "id": 10870,
    "type": "job",
    "url": "/api/v2/jobs/10870/",
        "project": {
            "id": 125,
            "name": "[Unix] Snapshot Create",
            "description": "Snapshot creation for VM",
            "status": "successful",
            "scm_type": "git",
            "allow_override": true
        },
        "project_update": {
            "id": 1087,
            "name": "[Unix] Snapshot Create",
            "description": "Snapshot creation for VM",
            "status": "successful",
            "failed": false
        },
    },
    "created": "2024-10-04T00:12:49.036211Z",
    "modified": "2024-10-04T00:12:49.285800Z",
    "name": "[Unix]Create Snapshot",
    "description": "Create snapshot for VM",
    "launch_type": "manual",
    "status": "successful",
    "execution_environment": 8,
    "failed": false,
    "started": "2024-10-04T00:12:49.584455Z",
    "finished": "2024-10-04T00:16:29.866690Z",
    "canceled_on": null,
    "elapsed": 220.282,
}


I am trying as below which is returning me 3!success’s though it should return only the last status state. But that value come anywhere in the json file. I mean it may come before the other two status field. I can’t use jq tool
My try
awk ‘$1 ~ /^”status”:/{print substr($2,1, lenghth($2)-1)}’ input.json

It sounds to me that your issue is that you can’t use jq. A secondary issue is that there are more than one statuses in the data and you don’t say which one you’re interested in (“the last” doesn’t mean anything for a set of unordered keys, but you probably mean the top-level one, right?).  Do you have other scripting languages available, like Perl or Python (which have support for parsing JSON)?

BTW, did you modify this JSON from what you’re actually working with? There seems to be bits missing before the project key and the very end. The current document is malformed.

Thanks kusalananda.. Sorry it was edited Jason since it will be difficult to read .. yes your understanding are correct. If I can use python or perl directly inside shell script then no issue..

"I can’t use jq tool" - you're in a managed environment? Put a formal request in for the tool to be installed. There's no point in using the wrong tool

This isn't valid JSON

@ChrisDavies yes this program will run in all the client servers so we don’t have authority to install any additional Sw..Yes since since it was huge Jason file i modified to fit in this small window.. I forgot to delete the comma

"we don’t have authority to install any additional Sw" - so put in a request to your Change Board for the correct tool. It's like using a knife instead of a screwdriver - you can usually make it work but it's inefficient and doesn't work well

"I forgot to delete the comma" - you can go back and fix it

It is, I suppose, necessary to weigh having a dependency on an external tool like Perl or Awk or jq, against having code that is known to not properly handle the input under some circumstances.

You have several answers - see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers for what to do next.

The document you're working with is malformed. You seem to have an excessive }, on line 20; also, the standard doesn't allow commas at the end of the last item of an object / array, so your document is using non-standard extensions, too.
If you were to fix the JSON so that it at least would validate as a well-formed (extended) JSON (by removing the excessive }, on line 20), in Perl, using the JSON::PP (core) module you could do:
perl -MJSON::PP -0777e 'print(JSON::PP -> new -> relaxed(1) -> decode(<>) -> {status})' input.json

The relaxed option tells the parser to not complain about commas at the end of the last item of an object / array.
If the comma at the end of the last item of the object is a refuse from manually editing the file, you may drop the call to relaxed(), so that the command would fail while parsing a non-standard JSON (whether this is desirable or not strictly depends on your use case):
perl -MJSON::PP -0777e 'print(JSON::PP -> new -> decode(<>) -> {status})' input.json

Both of these will output the value verbatim; if you need a newline at the end, add the -l option to either:
perl -MJSON::PP -l -0777e 'print(JSON::PP -> new -> relaxed(1) -> decode(<>) -> {status})' input.json

perl -MJSON::PP -l -0777e 'print(JSON::PP -> new -> decode(<>) -> {status})' input.json


These days, I prefer using the object-oriented interface (as in perl -MJSON::PP -0777E 'say JSON::PP->new->relaxed->decode(<>)->{status}') as it doesn't do the implicit UTF-8 decoding that the procedural interface does and avoids problems with non-UTF-8-encoded JSON (as  (potentially) produced by many tools) and is good enough for most purposes.

@StéphaneChazelas Yeah I got confused with JSON::PP, thanks for pointing that out. And thanks for addressing the "problem" with the procedural interface, although here I was kinda "forced" to use the OO interface regardless since there's no way to pass options to decode() directly using JSON::PP.

@StéphaneChazelas I added another version with -l, thanks

Thank you sorry it was edited by myself .. since it was huge .. I ll try with the above code

@user984993 No problem, I understand; if the input does not include non standard extensions, you may use just perl -MJSON::PP -0777e 'print(JSON::PP -> new -> decode(<>) -> {status})' input.json

Both are working flawlessly… Thanks a ton

@user984993 Yeah but the second version, if you're expecting a standard valid JSON, will fail if the JSON contains non-standard extensions; so, depending on your purpose, it may be desirable to choose one over the other. I'm glad that worked out for you

@kos how about using python like  python -c 'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["status"])'

@user984993 Yeah I suppose that also would work, but I'm not familiar with the nuances (will it allow parsing non-standard JSONs? Etc etc, although I understand the , at the end was also probably a refuse from manually editing the file)

When you get around installing jq, either system-wide or for a separate user (jq can be installed as a static binary with no dependencies), you could use this:
jq -e '.status == "successful"' file.json

If this returns the string true or exits with a zero exit status, the job was successful, and if it returns false or exits with a non-zero exit status, the status of the job was not successful.
The -e option to jq makes the utility exit with a zero exit status if the last evaluated expression is not false or null. The expression that is evaluated is a test for whether the top-level status key's value is the string successful.
In a script, you could use this like so:
if jq -e '.status == "successful"' file.json >/dev/null
then
    echo 'The job was successful'
else
    echo 'The job failed'
fi


If, for whatever reason, you had wanted to ensure that all values for any status key in the document was successful, you could do that with the following jq statement (here on several lines only for readability):
[
    .. |
    select(
        type == "object" and has("status")
    ).status == "successful"
] | all

This recurses through the document and picks out the value for the status key, wherever such a key is found.  A test is made on each found value, and if all tests generate a true value, the overall outcome is true.

Thanks a lot.. JQ is the easiest it seems .. but it is not available in RHEL7 package..

@user984993 https://stackoverflow.com/q/72813937/931027

Using any awk, assuming your input is formatted as shown in your question but without the extra }, in the middle of it:
$ cat tst.awk
$NF ~ /\{$/ { depth++ }
$1  ~ /^}/  { depth-- }
(depth == 1) && ($1 ~ /^"status"/) {
    sub(/,$/,"")
    print $NF
}


$ awk -f tst.awk file
"successful"

Regarding the use of print substr($2,1, lenghth($2)-1) in your code to remove the trailing , - there won't be a trailing , if "status" is the last line before the closing } so that would corrupt your output. That's why I'm using sub(/,$/,"") for that job instead - if the comma is there it'll be removed, if not then the sub() will do nothing.

Thanks Edd.. It was a manipulated json since I deleted some useless part to fit in this query.. Thank you very much for the solution also
